# using pact-broker webhooks locally?

Tags: pact-broker

I have setup the pact broker locally and able to publish the pacts which are also verified by the provider successfully. I am at the point to use webhook which kicks off a build of the provider project if the pact content has changed since the previous version. Can I use the webhook concept in my local because my consumer and provider are not configured in CI?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a local "CI server" on your machine. It doesn't really have to be a proper CI server, but it does have to be able to accept an HTTP request that will kick off a build somehow.

You should be able to create a very simple ruby/javascript/python HTTP server that will run the provider build in a backgrounded process when it receives a request. Or, you could install a copy of something like Jenkins locally.